# Vue 2.0 setting up routes - Do not use 'new' for side effects

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am configuring a vue project. I used the webpack template. ( npm install init webpack ). I am getting an error in the terminal --

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js

✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new  Do not use 'new' for side effects  
/Users/uz067252/Documents/Development/Vue/workex/vue-project/src/main.js:21:1
new Vue({
^


✘ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


Errors:
1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new
```

Here's the main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

// We want to apply VueResource and VueRouter
// to our Vue instance
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

// Pointing routes to the components they should use
var router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
    { path: '/hello', component: Hello },
    { path: '*', redirect: '/hello' }
]
})

new Vue({
el: '#app',
router: router,
render: h => h(App)
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That error is coming from your eslint code formatter, not from Vue.js itself.

Your webpack environment is configured to verify code before it builds and starts your app. While doing that, your **eslint** put out that warning.

To avoid it, do as follows (in the last 5 lines of your **main.js** file):

```js
new Vue({  // eslint-disable-line no-new
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

What you are doing above is disabling eslint warning for `new` only in that above line. Now your webpack will start your app normally.

The other option is to set a rule in `.eslintrc.js` (in the project root folder), where you can specify that `no-new` rule should be ignored. (not recommended in this case)

Comment: And how can I remove the linter from my project?

Comment: If you are starting a new project using webpack template (`vue init webpack my-project`), you will get an option to "Use ESLint to lint your code?", in which you can answer "n" or no. If you have an existing project in which you want to turn off linter, you can try the suggestions in this discussion: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73

Comment: I had an existing project, and what I did was changed my `.eslintignore` to read `*.js`. That did the trick for now! :-P

Comment: @dotslash I wouldnt remove eslint ^^

Comment: Do not recommend just disabling rules when there is an easy fix/accommodation.

Answer (score 14):

You can also set a vm var and mount separately

```
var vm = new Vue({router, render: h => h(App)})
vm.$mount('#app')
```

ref : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount

Comment: This is the best answer, because it actually removes the usage of `new` for side-effects. When not passing `el` to the constructor, there is no side-effect, and it's more clear what's going on. Also, this is similar to what you will need to do in Vue 3.

Answer (score 6):

This liner rule is useful and important. If you use any frameworks - for example Vue - that use the `new` operator side effect, wrap this in an anonymous function by adding three parentheses

```
(()=>code)();
```

in your code

```
(()=>new Vue({  // no linter directive need anymore
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    render: h => h(App)
}))();
```

Comment: Yes, I prefer this solution to re-directing linting. Seems to not have any unexpected results so far at least - and probably won't.

Comment: Now, what exactly is happening to cause this to satisfy 'no-new.' Is it because we are using IIFE to make this an _expression_ rather than a _statement?_

Comment: We tell to linter: "Hey linter!, We don't use the new object, which created by new operator, but we know it present. We (gc can) free the memory after this function ends."

Answer (score 5):

You are not assigning the value of the `new Vue(...)` statement to anything.

A `new` statement creates a new instance of an object. Normally this instance is assigned to a variable. If you do not assign the instance to a variable, then it is garbage collected.

The linter is assuming that, since you are not keeping a reference to the new instance, you are relying on a side effect from the operation, and this is a bad practice. An example of a side effect would be if the `new` operation modified the value of a global variable.